# solr.DirectUpdateHandler2 failed to instantiate

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have 4 SOLR indexes running on a single node Hadoop environment.
The VM went out of space so i freed some space on the OS but after i restarted the VM , the indexes were not starting.

The VM where I am running SOLR has 64 GB of RAM

I am getting solr.DirectUpdateHandler2 failed to instantiate error
I need help on this as my system is not working anymore due to this issue and the backup i have is old.

This is the error:

```
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'EMAIL_DOMAINS_shard1_replica1' is not available due to init failure: Error Instantiating Update Handler, solr.DirectUpdateHandler2 failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:752)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.checkProps(SolrDispatchFilter.java:768)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.getCoreByCollection(SolrDispatchFilter.java:742)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:325)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:211)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter$2.doFilter(SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.java:394)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:552)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.java:399)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:86)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating Update Handler, solr.DirectUpdateHandler2 failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:893)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:663)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:498)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:262)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:256)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
... 1 more
  Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating Update Handler, solr.DirectUpdateHandler2 failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:581)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createUpdateHandler(SolrCore.java:637)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:855)
... 8 more
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:567)
... 10 more
  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.start(DFSOutputStream.java:2359)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForAppend(DFSOutputStream.java:1934)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callAppend(DFSClient.java:1853)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.append(DFSClient.java:1878)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.append(DFSClient.java:1871)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:329)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:325)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.append(DistributedFileSystem.java:325)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.append(FileSystem.java:1172)
at org.apache.solr.update.HdfsTransactionLog.<init>(HdfsTransactionLog.java:93)
at org.apache.solr.update.HdfsUpdateLog.init(HdfsUpdateLog.java:200)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.<init>(UpdateHandler.java:136)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.<init>(UpdateHandler.java:94)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.<init>(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:100)
... 15 more
```

Comment: Could you try to add a more infos and a detailed error message?

Comment: this is the error

Answer (score 0):

In the exception is clearly written that you have an Out Of Memory (OOM) problem.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

Given that you already had an out of space, please double check if you have already freed enough disk space.

After this, even if there are many reasons for an OOM, the common reason is that your JVM hasn't enough memory so double check your heap size configuration (i.e. `–Xms` and `–Xmx`).

If freeing more disk space and allocate more memory heap doesn't resolve your problem, I suggest also to:

- check and if you need to increase user limits (`ulimit –a`), this means user max thread limits, max open processes and max open files limits.
- check threads system wide settings and, even in this case, raise the limit if you need it.

On the other hand, rarely happens that you have allocated so much heap space or so much resource that the operating system has no enough room to run your application.

In conclusion just try to find the right balance between allocated resources and application needs.